# getting upside down change left to right and vice versa

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a 2D game in Unity. My player moves right and left as he supposed to . **But when he gets upside down** the right becomes left and left becomes the right, so when moving right he goes left and vice versa. Here is my code:

```
if (Input.touchCount > 0) {  
    if(Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {

            if(Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition.x > 0) // is player moving right

            transform.Translate(new Vector2(Time.deltaTime *Speed,0));

            else if(Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition.x < 0) // is player moving left

                transform.Translate(new Vector2(- Time.deltaTime *Speed,0));
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html):

> If `relativeTo` is left out or set to `Space.Self` the movement is applied relative to the transform's local axes.

You are applying your movement *relative to the object you are moving* so, when the object is upside down, it's "left" is the user's "right."

Try this instead:

```
transform.Translate(new Vector2(Time.deltaTime *Speed,0), Space.World);
```